# How to override default root URL of plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, templating

how can I override default root URL behavior via routes? I did following but not working:

```
'pluginname/' => array('action' => 'pluginName/Controller/actionName');
```

my template file name is `index`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
public function registerCpRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'settings/plugins/pluginname/index' => 'pluginname/index'
    );
}
```

Comment: do I need to add `settings` anyway?

Comment: You don't have to have settings.